# using Python 2.7 os.walk to find a file then parsing that file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I'm trying to find a file then parse it, but I'm having trouble calling it in my second part of my script:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
import os, fnmatch


def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename

for filename in find_files('c:/Python27','*file.xml'): 
    print ('Found file.xml:', filename)

def xmlparse():
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Game')
    for item in itemlist:
        year = item.getElementsByTagName('Year')
    for s in year:
        print item.attributes['name'].value, s.attributes['value'].value
```

Comment: What kind of "trouble" are you having? Is it not parsing the right file for example?

Comment: Its not grabbing the file at all.  I don't get an output. So I'm wondering if I'm using the right syntax in my def xmlparse.  Am I looking for the filename or do I call for the file.xml in another way?

Comment: You don't seem to do anything in your xmlparse() as you have the loop outside the function. I don't see `protocol` defined anywere either

Comment: The xml parse alone will find the data I need if I add the path for the file. However I want to search for the file because there may be more then one file in different folders.

Comment: As it stands nothing is happening in your parse function, you also have variables defined you never use and your indentations seem wrong

Comment: Ok, so how do I call the my file that I find in my def find_files function?

Comment: There are multiples issues in your function too so it is not just a case of passing the filename to your function. What is protocol and what are you supposed to do with year?

Comment: Actually disregard the protocol. I edited the script.  That was a typo. When I remove the def xmlparse() and just run the script I get the path and only one game name and year.  It doesn't give me the whole list for some reason.

Comment: Following your recent edit, you might also want to move the `for` loop of the year inside the `for` loop of the itemlist. I'll edit my answer with more details.

Comment: ok, your suggestion actually worked a little it brings up some of the games and year but not all of them which is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change your `xmlparse` function to take a filename as argument. You just need to change the function declaration to this:

```
def xmlparse(filename):
```

Then, you might also want to move your `for` loop from the middle of your script to the bottom of your script. You could then call `xmlparse` with each filename returned by `find_files` like this:

```
for filename in find_files('c:/Python27','*file.xml'):
    print ('Found file.xml:', filename)
    xmlparse(filename)
```

Following your recent edit, you might also want to fix your `xmlparse` function to loop over each year instead of just the last year:

```
    for item in itemlist:
        year = item.getElementsByTagName('Year')
        for s in year:
            print item.attributes['name'].value, s.attributes['value'].value
```

Comment: There are numerous mistakes in the parse function so just passing the file is not going to work

Comment: Sure, but at least the parse function will be called and the original poster can presumably take it from there.

Comment: I would rather  wait for the OP to reply to the comments than to add an answer that is still not going to work

Comment: I actually edited the script and its working, its just getting the last entry of my xml doc. How would I fix that?

Comment: I mentioned earlier that you need to "move the `for` loop of the year inside the `for` loop of the itemlist". If you look at the last code block in my answer, you'll notice that the `for` loop of the year is indented more than the `for` loop of the itemlist. If your editor is showing you the same thing but you're still getting the last entry, make sure you're only indenting with spaces and not tabs.